# Why does Access break up JOIN queries by table and then pass each to ODBC (SQL Server) separately?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, join

Why does Access 2013 take a perfectly good query like:

```
Select t1.A,t2.b,t3.c
from T1
Inner Join t2 on t2.a = t1.a
Inner Join t3 on t3.a = t1.a
```

and break it down to 3 different jobs (sessions)

```
session 1:   Select a from t1
Session 2.   select b from t2
session 3.   select c from t3
```

Comment: Probably because Access is not SQL.  It gives you the ability to write very similar code.  But more advanced stuff needs to be broken down into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Access (the application) uses the Access Database Engine (a.k.a "ACE", previously "Jet") to process its queries. Consequently it tends to treat tables as discrete entities, much like the SQL Server query engine would do with its own tables. (You might ask SQL Server for information from `Table1 INNER JOIN Table2` but at some point in the low-level processing of the query the SQL Server engine has to pull data from the individual tables.)

In your particular case it might seem puzzling that ACE extracts information from each table separately when all three tables are in SQL Server and it could be considerably more efficient to pass the whole query off to SQL Server for processing. However, a given ODBC Linked Table can be backed by any number of "database technologies" with widely varying capabilities and degrees of interoperability.

For example, your query could have just as easily been a case where:

- [t1] is a local Access table,
- [t2] is an ODBC Linked Table on SQL Server, and
- [t3] is a table of data in a CSV file.

ACE can process those sorts of queries, but it can only do so by being able to accommodate the general case, and that might be at the expense of optimizing for particular cases (like yours).

If you *really need* to have the whole query run on the SQL Server then you can always

1. create a [pass-through query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/process-sql-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-HA010206488.aspx) in Access, or
2. create a SQL Server VIEW for that query and then use an ODBC Linked "Table" to that VIEW (instead of linking to the individual SQL Server tables).

Comment: Great answer (+upvote) As you note those ODBC tables can be from separate data sources. Strange is some “monster” 8+ large table queries via ODBC have worked near instant in Access to SQL server – I trying to figure out (find) what criteria JET uses for splitting out the joins as selects since some queries work VERY well. And often in place of pass-though is to save the sql as a VIEW sql side and link to that. This allows one to edit/modify native t-sql with SQL studio tools. And this simple linked table not only filters very well but also is updatable as compared to pass-though (read only)

Comment: Good to know!  SQL Server does the same thing with Linked Servers...  have to be very careful how you author the query.